# Get an int? from db using DbDataReader

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any smart way to abbreviate this obscenity? It works, but it's unreadable...

```
int? myVal = r.IsDBNull(r.GetOrdinal("colName")) ? (int?)null : r.GetInt32(r.GetOrdinal("colName"));
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You could put that code into an extension method on the DbDataReader. That way, the horrible-looking code it hidden away behind a nicer looking `GetNullableInt32()` call.

Comment: @adrianbanks your comment deserves to be an answer!!

Comment: @adrianbanks: You should make that an answer, not a comment...

Comment: Only tangentially related, but you can use `default(int?)` instead of `(int?)null`. Maybe it's not a great improvement, but casting null just to get the compiler to parse the type bugs me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could put that code into an extension method on the `DbDataReader` (or even better on the `IDataReader` interface that it implements). That way, the horrible-looking code is hidden away behind a nicer looking GetNullableInt32() call:

```
public static class IDataReaderExtensions
{
    public static int? GetNullableInt32(this IDataReader r, string columnName)
    {
        int? myVal = r.IsDBNull(r.GetOrdinal(columnName)) 
                        ? (int?) null : 
                        r.GetInt32(r.GetOrdinal(columnName));
        return myVal;
    }
}
```

You can then call it using:

```
IDataReader reader = ...;
int? value = reader.GetNullableInt32("colName");
```

As Ian points out, it would be better to call `r.GetOrdinal()` just the once:

```
public static class IDataReaderExtensions
{
    public static int? GetNullableInt32(this IDataReader r, string columnName)
    {
        int ordinal = r.GetOrdinal(columnName);
        int? myVal = r.IsDBNull(ordinal) 
                        ? (int?) null : 
                        r.GetInt32(ordinal);
        return myVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is better if you only call GetOrdinal(columnName) once.

Comment: @Ian: I agree (I used Palantir's original code to demonstrate how to make it into an extension method).

Answer (score 3):

Further to [Adrian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021832/get-an-int-from-db-using-dbdatareader/4021885#4021885), you could make a generic extension method to cater for all types:

```
int? myVal = r.GetValue<int?>("colName");

// ...

public static class DataReaderExtensions
{
    public static T GetValue<T>(this IDataReader dr, string columnName)
    {
        return dr.GetValue<T>(dr.GetOrdinal(columnName));
    }

    public static T GetValue<T>(this IDataReader dr, int columnOrdinal)
    {
        // does the column contain null?
        if (dr.IsDBNull(columnOrdinal))
        {
            // is T either a ref type or a nullable value type?
            Type t = typeof(T);
            if (!t.IsValueType || (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) != null))
            {
                // return null
                return default(T);
            }
        }

        // get the column value, cast it as T and return it
        // this will throw if the value isn't convertible/unboxable to T
        return (T)dr.GetValue(columnOrdinal);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  I often put this code in a method and call it.  That method could end up in a common "helper" class or I suppose even an extension method (though I'm not personally a fan of those because they're hard for other people to discover).